# PSRAM with 32-bit data bit depth

Tags: psram

Although there are lots of PSRAMs transmitting data at 16-bit bit depth, it seems almost impossible to see a 32-bit PSRAM. Is there any reason for not making such product? (I'm not asking for product recommendation, please do not mention any product No in this thread.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the number of data bits requires an increase in the number of pins or bumps on the package, which increases the physical size and cost of the package. Note that PSRAMs typically do not multiplex the address pins as DRAMs do.

So, the 32-bit version is a more expensive product that takes more board space and has a smaller market than the combined market for 16-bit **and** 32-bit PSRAMs. The economic incentive is for the PSRAM manufacturer to sell a 16-bit version, and let those who need a 32-bit data bus combine two ICs at the board level.

Comment: Even 48, 64, 80, 96, 112 and 128 bit PSRAMs may be build by using several 16 bit PSRAMs if neccessary,

Comment: Then can the total throughput be scaled up?

Comment: If you mean the throughput of the RAM then yes, it can be scaled up. If you measure throughput in bytes/sec and increase the width of the data bus then the throughput goes up proportionally. However, the cost of wiring and interconnections also goes up.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! Given the circumstance that there are really not many options, using two PSRAMs seems to be reasonable. Also 32-bit wide SDRAM has 90 pins, so two 54-pins PSRAM would be not that bad.